# PHP non-case sensitive sort not working

Tags: php

The following code should put Banana after apple but instead it goes to the end.

```
$json='{"apple":null,"orange":["s","s2"],"pear":null}';

$json=json_decode($json,true);

$json['Banana']=NULL;

ksort ($json, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

print_r($json);
```

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dJZxij).

Comment: Seems to be only in PHP 5.4 this will work.

Comment: You most likely use a PHP version < 5.4 [_"5.4.0 Added support for SORT_NATURAL and SORT_FLAG_CASE as sort_flags" _](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: I am running 5.4 and this still works. Can you `phpinfo()` and tell us what you see?

Comment: I just said it's only for 5.4 - I am below this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SORT_NATURAL` and `SORT_FLAG_CASE` only work in php version > 5.4.0

from here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

in Changelog

```
5.4.0   Added support for SORT_NATURAL and SORT_FLAG_CASE as sort_flags
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function natksort(&$array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    natcasesort($keys);

    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
    }

    $array = $new_array;
    return true;
}

$json='{"apple":null,"orange":["s","s2"],"pear":null}';
$json=json_decode($json,true);
$json['Banana']=NULL;

natksort($json);

print_r($json);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => 
    [Banana] => 
    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => s2
        )

    [pear] => 
)
```